# C++: Friend Functions

Tags: c++, function, friend

```
class A {
  friend void display();
};

friend void display() {
  cout<<"friend";
}

int main() {
  display();
}
```

Works fine...

```
class A {
  friend void display() {
    cout<<"friend";
  }
};

int main() {
  display();
}
```

It shows :

```
display is not declared in this scope.
```

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 4):

In the first example (which should fail to compile for another reason: You can't use `friend` when defining the function) you define the function `display` to be in the global scope.

In the second example the `display` function is not a member function (it's in the scope surrounding the class), but it's still declared only in the scope of the `A` class. You need to re-declare it in the global scope for it to actually be in the global scope.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that you can redeclare friend-defined functions to make them available without ADL.